# Conditionally rendering a component with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

With styled components, I can pass in values and then get conditional css based on those values. For instance, I can do,

```
const ContainerStyled = styled.div<{isOpen: boolean}>`
  ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen
    ? background-color: red
    : ''
  }
`
```

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to conditionally render a different component, based on that value? For instance, something like,

```
const ContainerStyled = styled(isOpen ? ArrowUpIcon : ArrowDownIcon)`
  ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen
    ? background-color: red
    : ''
  }
`
```

Comment: On which scope is `isOpen`? On writing `styled(isOpen ? ArrowUpIcon : ArrowDownIcon)` does `isOpen` already evaluated? Your example not clear. Please try showing expected usecase of rendering

Comment: Also, it seems like an XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/, please explain what the actual issue and not how you trying to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you asking if you can change **the styled target depending on condition**.

For that you need to make simple steps:

1. The custom [component has to pass the `className` prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components).
2. Use [`as` API](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) with condition.

In the next example, the button toggles between rendering a `styled.div` and `styled(Component)`.

```
const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? `red` : `blue`)};
`;

const Component = ({ className }) => <div className={className}>Hello</div>;

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, toggle] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  return (
    <>
      <Container as={isOpen ? Component : 'div'} isOpen={isOpen} />
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit misty-meadow-j27j7]

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `as` [polymorphic prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) using `attrs` [chainable method](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) based on passed `isOpen` prop:

```
const ContainerStyled = styled(ArrowDownIcon).attrs(({ isOpen }) => ({
  as: isOpen ? ArrowUpIcon : undefined
}))`
  background-color: ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen ? 'red' : ''};
`;
```